# Fetch child record for each Parent template in xslt and print them in same row

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a requirement wherein I need to process and display records associated to xml. The xml being used is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<School>
<Class>
        <Student name="Test1"/>  
        <Student name="Test2/"> 
        <Result marks="100"/>
        <Result marks="80"/>
</Class>
<Class>
        <Student name="Test3"/>
</Class>
</School>
```

I am using th following xslt to process it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="School" />      
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="School">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Class" />      
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Class">
    <xsl:for-each select="Student">
        <p> <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>  </p>
    </xsl-for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Currently, I am getting output as:
Test1
Test2
Test3
However, I need to generate an output as:
Test1 100
Test2 80
Test3
There is a class which contains students, some classes contains result as well, the classes which have result have it in the same number as the number of students and I need to associate the 1st student with the first result, 2nd student with 2nd result and so on. In case if a class does not have a result, then just the student name will be displayed. How can I achieve this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please respect the time of the people trying to help you: make sure you post code that can be used ***as is*** to reproduce your problem. `<Student name="Test2/"> ` is not XML. `</xsl-for-each>` is not XSLT. And there is no `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<xsl:template match="Class">
    <xsl:for-each select="Student">
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="../Result[$i]/@marks"/>
       </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```